# Write an R function which accepts a list of integers and returns only the odd values in the original list

Tags: r

Write an R function which accepts a list of integers and returns only the odd
values in the original list. R has a number of built-in datasets; one of them is
called Nile and a data frame containing these data is added to your working
environment with the command data(‘Nile’). How many of the entries in this
dataset are odd?

What I've written is

```
return.odd<-function(y)return(y[y%%2=1])

length(return.odd(Nile))
```

But it returns

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "return.odd<-function(y)return(y[y%%2="
```

and

```
Error in return.odd(Nile) : could not find function "return.odd"
```

Could you please tell where my mistakes are?

Comment: Should be `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: Your function does not exist because of an unexpected affectation in a selection

Comment: @C.Braun yep that's the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return_odd <- function(x) {

x[x %% 2 == 1]

}

length(return_odd(Nile))

[1] 27
```